# Is $\sum_0^\infty (-1)^k z^{k-1}$ equal to $\sum_{-1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} z^{k}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is $$\sum_0^\infty (-1)^k z^{k-1}$$
equal to $$\sum_{-1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} z^{k}$$
i.e am I allowed to reindex the beginning of series ?

Comment: **Yes**­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and you can even generalize

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{k-1}=\sum_{k=-n}^\infty (-1)^{k+n} z^{k+n-1}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^0 (-1)^k z^{-k-1}$$